# Strip Ubuntu Desktop to become Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, desktop

We installed Ubuntu Desktop as our dev server, and now its sitting in a DMZ, so there is no porpuse for the whole grafic interface, since we only access it via SSH.

Is there any way to strip all the uneeded packaging of ubuntu Desktop and convertit to ubuntu server withought going and removing each thing by hand ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apt-get autoremove ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install ubuntu-server

should do it...

Comment: In ubuntu 11.10: Unable to locate package ubuntu-server